# Java Script With Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

How can I Implement the following :
I Created Custom Edit Form for my custom List with tow field ( title , checkedIn ), when you click save button i want
to show alert message (yes/No) , if You choose Yes , then Set Value of checkedIn Field to True , after that save the form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PreSaveAction** function allows to override functionality when Save button is clicked. PreSaveAction function executes the code written for validation on click of Save button.
Place the following function:

`function PreSaveAction()
{
  if (confirm('Yes/No')) {
       $('input[title="checkedIn "]').val("True");
    }
}`

Comment: i want to redirect to list page after clicking yes , and the item get change

Comment: i did this  :
<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="if (!PreSaveAction()) return false; {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={home.aspx}')}" />
       
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction()
{
  if (confirm('Yes/No')) {
       $('input[title="checkedIn"]').val("True");
    }
}
</script>